# How to get owner element of a text node?

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I have this data:

```
<data>
  <foo>foo text</foo>
  data text
    <bar>
      bar text
      <baz>text</baz>
      <baz>text</baz>
      bar text
    </bar>
   data text
</data>
```

and I need get all text values in order, modify text inside "baz" tag and print. My code is:

```
text = []
for element in etree.xpath("./*"):
    text.extend(element.xpath("./text()"))
    if element.tag == 'bar':
        text.extend(["baz " + s for s in element.xpath("./baz/text()")])
print '\n'.join([s.strip() for s in text if s.strip()])
```

output is:

```
foo text
bar text
bar text
baz text
baz text
```

but I need:

```
foo text
data text
bar text
baz text
baz text
bar text
data text
```

How can I get `text()` of node in order and without lost `data text` text?

**Edit**
I know about `etree.xpath(".//text()")` which can give me all text in order, but
I need to modify text inside `baz` tag. This is a point. How can I get tag value of every element of `.//text()` XPath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're using `lxml`, you can call `getparent()` function to get owner element of a text node, for example :

```
import lxml.etree
etree = lxml.etree.fromstring('''
<data>
  <foo>foo text</foo>
  data text
    <bar>
      bar text
      <baz>text</baz>
      <baz>text</baz>
      bar text
    </bar>
   data text
</data>
''')

for text in etree.xpath("//text()[normalize-space()]"):
    parenttag = text.getparent().tag
    print(parenttag, text)
```

XPath expression `//text()[normalize-space()]` simply means return all *non-empty* text nodes in the XML document.

**output :**

```
('foo', 'foo text')
('foo', '\n  data text\n    ')
('bar', '\n      bar text\n      ')
('baz', 'text')
('baz', 'text')
('baz', '\n      bar text\n    ')
('bar', '\n   data text\n')
```

Comment: My problem solved, tnx. But I have a quick question. Why parent tags for 'data text' values 'foo' and 'bar'? I think it must be 'data' tag. Looks like it's not parent tag, just previous

Comment: Full explanation of this behavior can be found in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31770189/why-getparent-dont-work-as-expected